# Error fetching a variable from another class (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get the value of a variable from the didSelectRow function and put it into my prepareForSegue function, but for whatever reason the value it is fetching is also blank. This is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "search", sender: nil)
    self.newSearch = "Example"

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let stockController = segue.destination as! Data
    stockController.symbolID = self.newSearch
}
```

And when we're brought to this other cell it symbolID is always blank. Is this an issue with the formatting or with the following viewController?

Comment: call performSegue function after newSearch assign.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

     self.newSearch = "Example"
     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "search", sender: nil)

}
```